# AWS Appsync: How can I create a resolver that retrieves the details for an array of identifiers?

Tags: graphql, aws-appsync, resolver

This feels basic, so I would expect to find this scenario mentioned, but I have searched and can't find an example that matches my scenario.  I have 2 end points (I am using HTTP data sources) that I'm trying to combine.

Class:

```js
{
   id: string,
   students: [
      <studentID1>,
      <studentID2>,
      ...
   ]
 }
```

and Student:

```
{
    id: String,
    lastName: String
}
```

What I would like is a schema that looks like this:

```
Student: {
   id: ID!
   lastName: String
}
Class: {
   id: ID!,
   studentDetails: [Student]
}
```

From reading, I know that I need some sort of resolver on Class.studentDetails that will return an array/List of student objects.  Most of the examples I have seen show retrieving the list of Students based on class ID (ctx.source.id), but that won't work in this case.  I need to call the students endpoint 1 time per student, passing in the student ID (I cannot fetch the list of students by class ID).

Is there a way to write a resolver for Class/studentDetails that loops through the student IDs in Class and calls my students endpoint for each one?

I was thinking something like this in the Request Mapping Template:

```
#set($studentDetails = [])
#foreach($student in $ctx.source.students) 
   #util.qr(list.add(...invoke web service to get student details...))
#end
$studentDetails
```

Edit: After reading Lisa Shon's comment below, I realized that the batch resolver for DynamoDB data sources that does this, but I don't see a way to do that for HTTP data sources.

Comment: Have you looked at [Batch Resolvers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/tutorial-dynamodb-batch.html)? And sounds like your student table is a single table so you can do something like this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/tutorial-dynamodb-batch.html#single-table-batch

Comment: It looks like Batch Resolvers work if your data source is DynamoDB, but mine is HTTP.  I edited my post to be explicit about that.

Answer (score 2):

It's not ideal, but you can create an intermediate type.

```
type Student {
  id: ID!
  lastName: String
}
type Class {
  id: ID!,
  studentDetails: [StudentDetails]
}
type StudentDetails {
  student: Student
}
```

In your resolver template for `Class`, create a list of those student ids

```
#foreach ($student in $class.students)
  $util.qr($studentDetails.add({"id": "$student.id"}))
#end
```

and add it to your response object. Then, hook a resolver to the `student` field of `StudentDetails` and you will then be able to use `$context.source.id` for the individual student API call. Each `id` will be broken out of the array and be its own web request.

Comment: We decided not to use AppSync, so I probably won't try this out, but it looks like it would work.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I opened a case with AWS Support and was told that the only way they know to do this is to create a Lambda Resolver that:

1. Takes an array of student IDs
2. Calls the students endpoint for each one
3. Returns an array of student details information

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling your student endpoint in the response, use a pipeline resolver and stitch the response from different steps using stash, context (prev.result/result), etc.